# Reading csv files: There are values which contain "E" and R reads it as a number

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

This might be a very basic issue so I apologise beforehand. I'm trying to read a csv file which contains several columns with stock information. One of these columns contains an identifier (unique code, named "CUSIP"), which is composed of numbers and letters (e.g. L8681T102). Some of these codes also contain the letter "E" (e.g. 75062E10) and when I read the csv file, this code appears as "7.51E+110" instead of the original.

I tried to use ColClasses to specify that the column is character, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just to cover all our bases: the argument to set column classes when using `read.csv/table` is `colClasses`, not `ColClasses`. Some example code and a few lines of data would help in creating a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: Please show the code you tried. Most likely you just have an argument in the wrong place or something.

Answer (score 2):

Using `read.table` and `colClasses` will work fine, there's no need to start using other packages:

```
> read.table(text = "x,y,z\n1,2,75062E10",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
  x y          z
1 1 2 7.5062e+14

> read.table(text = "x,y,z\n1,2,75062E10",sep = ",",header = TRUE,colClasses = c(NA,NA,"character"))
  x y        z
1 1 2 75062E10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with read_csv instead and get a tibble and specify each column in the following way. I find tibbles way easier to manage and faster to deal with, only their creation requires more time than dataframes, but usually I never create one, always read csv as them.

```
library(tidyverse)
read_csv("filename", col_types = cols(
  name= col_character(),
  numberwith.00= col_double(),
  time= col_datetime(format = "")
  ))
```